# Fast Javascript Table sorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with about 250 rows (may double within 6 months), and 50 columns on [this page](http://www.reviews-web-hosting.com/wizard.html) (warning: slow with IE). I'm using the [JQuery Table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). But it is too slow with IE 7: it gives a warning about a slow javascript, and ask if I want to stop it. I've spent a lot of time to improve performances, so it works fine for all other browsers:

- sort text and digit only
- removed all but 2 parsers
- created an extra table that contains all the values, much faster than doing node.textContent() for each cell
- removed lowercase, trim, etc.

My version of the javascript is [here](http://www.reviews-web-hosting.com/js/jquery.tablesorter.js). I think I cannot optimize it much more. I am looking for another fast implementation of a table sorter, or any good optimization I may have forgot, so that IE 7 won't complain about the execution time.

**Edit:** I've disabled sorting on 35 columns, it is still too long for IE

Comment: You can put a lighter jockey on a horse but at some point the horse can only go so fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) an extremely fast table sort javascript library. (not JQuery)

Comment: I've used this in the past and it works really well. Some times you have to use their custom attributes for dates, but overall it is very solid.

Comment: Very nice library but what if i don't want to use all headers for sorting?

Comment: Could you post the name of the previously linked script so others can Google it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of Christian Bach's jQuery table sorter ... http://tablesorter.com/docs/

- Compact and fast
- Sort on multiple columns
- Dynamic zebra stripe
- Optional metadata extension makes things even easier
- Parsers for sorting text, html, numbers, whatever (easy to customize)
- CSS styleable headers (of course)
- Cross-browser: IE 6.0+, FF 2+, Safari 2.0+, Opera 9.0+

[image]

**EDIT**: Anyone interested in tablesorter should see what Mottie has done with it: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter

Comment: The last code change is from 2008 is it compatible with the latest jQuery?

Comment: I think he's been too busy to maintain it, but Mottie has done incredible work with the code, including updating for jQuery 1.9 ... https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter

Answer (score 1):

Most JScript solutions that work slow have a lot of interaction with the DOM. At the moment that you're doing DOM-level edits row-per-row it will take long in IE. If you're building the HTML in a string and then put it at once in the DOM, it'll go a lot quicker. (There were some demos at the last PDC showing exactly that.)

But the moral of the story here is that your table is quite big. You might think of using REST, with table paging and sorting and some server-side logic. I think that can be a lot quicker and will work fine with JQuery. (And it is still an AJAX solution.) It might even save you some bandwidth...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out any references to applyWidget and their respective bindings as well as removing unused parsers made a big difference to a 500 row table in IE6 (yeah, I know, but it still won't die).

Comment: It is clear about widgets, but what kind of a parsers do U mean?

Answer (score 0):

One of the worst things you can do is use eval() and I see that in your code. You should profile your code and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: That eval() looks like it is called once per sort.. but it does look like it's doing something ugly.

Answer (score 0):

A great and robust option is this jQuery plugin, called [DataTables](http://datatables.net/).

- Variable length pagination
- On-the-fly filtering
- Multi-column sorting with data type detection
- Smart handling of column widths
- Display data    from almost any data source DOM, Javascript array,
  Ajax file and    server-side processing (PHP, C#, Perl, Ruby, AIR,
  Gears etc)
- Scrolling options for table viewport
- Fully internationalisable
- jQuery UI ThemeRoller support
- Rock solid - backed by a suite of 2900 unit tests
- Wide variety of plug-ins inc. Editor, TableTools, FixedColumns    and
  more
- It's free!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with seriously large databases try **server side with DataTables** (jQuery plugin).

Basically all of the paging, filtering, sorting etc that DataTables does can be handed off to a server (or any other data source).

Full example here:
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score -1):

Problem in the function buildCache(table)
Line 219
Error : 'all_data' non defined